# Mount or copy TFVC workspace into Docker container

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I currently have a computer acting as our build server. This computer has a TFVC workspace set up containing the source code repo. When the build process does a "Get Latest" it gets the latest checked-in files since the last build and everything builds fine.

I now need to set up a docker container to do the actual build.

I have mounted the source code repo folder into the container and created a workspace based on the existing workspace using the `tf workspace /template` command however when it comes to do the "Get Latest" it is downloading the whole repo from scratch, even though the most recent files are already mounted inside the container.

How can I use the existing workspace inside the container so it doesnt try to pull down the whole of the repo?

Answer (score 0):

Although less than ideal, the following seems to get me by.

If I mount the repo folder when the container starts, then use `tf.exe` with the `/updateComputerName` switch it seems to "work".

It still does not use the existing local workspace (`$tf`) correctly, instead it creates a `$tf1` (I have no idea why) but I can simply delete that when the container has done it's job.